# Strange javascript notation - variable declaration with colon?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking through some library javascript source code and I've found a statement that I totally don't understand. This library is based on **dojo** and uses its implementation of "class inheritance".  Here is a simplified version of code that is a subject:

```js
dojo.declare("myCustomClass", {
    constructor:function(){
        // what does this statement mean?
        isContentShowing : false;

        //here some code that uses isContentShowing in callbacks
        dojo.connect(this, "fakeEvent", this, function(){
            if(this.isContentShowing){
            //do some stuff
            }
            //do more stuff
        });
    }
});
```

So the question is what does the `isContentShowing: false;` inside function body mean?

Comment: If that is literally the code, that's a syntax error.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan That's not. I think pst explained it quite well. Everybody forgets about labels nowadays...

Comment: @MaxArt: hmm... I thought JavaScript didn't support them. I *know* about them (and thought about them before adding the comment!), but thought they weren't in JavaScript. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a variable. It is a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

> Provides a statement with an identifier that you can refer to using a break or continue statement.

In this case, it is *useless*: it is not used as a label, it does *not* perform an assignment, and the result of evaluating `false` is discarded.

I suspect a `=` *and* `this` are desired as `this.isContentShowing = false` makes more sense given the conditional below. Perhaps the original author never ran into/realized this bug due to `this.isContentShowing` evaluating to `undefined` (and thus still being falsey, like, well, `false`) later on.

Or, as Chris suggests in a comment, the intent might have been:

```
dojo.declare("myCustomClass", {
  isContentShowing : false, // but , and not ;
  constructor:...
});
```

Comment: Extremely confusing. Why putting `false;` right after that? I'm guessing it's some kind of bug...

Comment: @MaxArt It is confusing - I believe that it is indeed incorrect code.

Comment: @MaxArt - yes it's a bug, though as pst explained it's not a syntax error. The original coder most likely intended `this.isContentShowing=false;`.

Comment: Or perhaps `isContentShowing: false,` outside the function (inside the object literal).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan That could very well have been the intent, although as the `;` would need to be a `,` in the object-literal... but in any case, as good an explanation for the [misguided] appearance as mine :-)

Answer (score -1):

This is called object literal in Javascript. It contains key value pair, e.g:

```
var car = {
    color: 'blue',
    price: 10000
}
```

so when you call `car['color'] or car.color` it will return `blue`. In the my example, color is the key and value is 'blue'. That's called key value pair.

Anyway, in the your example `this.isContentShowing` will return false by default.

Comment: In your answer you've shown an object literal. In the question the code is defining a _function_, not an object literal. In context it's fairly clear that the original coder meant `this.isContentShowing = false;`. In the question `this.isContentShowing` will return `undefined`, _not_ `false` (though in the context of an if condition `undefined` will act the same as `false`).

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like a misplaced statement (interpreted instead as a label, as explained by @pst) That property should likely have been a peer of `constructor:`  All properties on the object passed to `dojo.declare` are put on the Object prototype.  Because an undefined value is falsey, in the end, the behavior is pretty much the same.  Declaring falsey properties on the prototype is of limited value, unless someone is actually iterating through properties to check for existence, as `dojo.parse` does.